# How to use Jsoup to find a JSON data embedded inside script tag in the html response?

Tags: java, android, html, json, jsoup

I have an HTML. It contains script tags embedded with JSON data. I want to get the JSON content from the script tag.

I tried Jsoup but no luck. Could anyone please suggest me how to use JSOUP or any other library to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getElementsByTag()` method.

For example:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlResponse.string());
Elements scriptElements = doc.getElementsByTag("script");

for (Element element :scriptElements ){                
        //...node.getWholeData();           
  }
```